# How do I best store API data into a Python class instance variable?

Tags: python, class

I would like some advice on how to best design a class and it's instance variables. I initialize the class with self.name. However, the main purpose of this class it to retrieve data from an API passing self.name as a parameter, and then parsing the data accordingly. I have a class method called `fetch_data(self.name)` that makes the API request and returns ALL data. I want to store this data into a class instance variable, and then call other methods on that variable. For example, `get_emotions(json), get_personality_traits(json), and get_handle(json)`, all take the same dictionary as a parameter, assign it to their own local variables, and then manipulate it accordingly.

I know I can make fetch_data(self.name) return data, and then call fetch_data(self.name) within the other methods, assign the return value to a local variable, and manipulate that. The problem is then I will need to call the API 5 times rather than 1, which I can't do for time and money reasons.

So, how do I make the result of `fetch_data(self.name)` global so that all methods within the class have access to the main data object? I know this is traditionally done in an instance variable, but in this scenario I can't initiliaze the data since I don't have it until after I call `fetch_data()`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you want to make a class here. Just keep the API response as a list of dictionaries and write function (not class methods) to work with that. In any case, this question is far too vague.

Comment: Can you give exemplary code (or pseudo code) instead of textually describing it, please?

Comment: Why would I write functions rather than class methods, though? I want the program to get to the point where I just write user.emotions, user.personality, etc. accordingly

Comment: What's wrong with initializing with `self.data = None`, and then setting it to actual data that you fetch later?

Comment: One could also ask "why write a class when you could just write `emotions(user)`?"

Comment: Why not split the class into two: one containing all API-related methods (like `fetch_data()`) and a second, which objects will be returned by `fetch_data()`?

Comment: @MarkkuK. so simply but exactly the solution I was looking for! Still new to programming and OOP in particular so I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just need to do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = None

    def fetch_data(self):
        if self.data is None:
            # Only call the API once
            self.data = self.really_fetch_data()
        return self.data

    def get_emotions(self):
        emotions = self.fetch_data().get("emotions")
        ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot @MarkkuK

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try to solve this as you described?

For example, you can take this as a starting point:

```
import json

class APIBundle(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = None
        self.update()

    def update():
        response = json.loads(API_request(self.name))
        # Do some parsing on response
        self.data = response

    def get_emotions():
        # Work through current data state
        # and filter as desired
        result = []
        for message in self.data['messages']:
            if message.find(':)') != -1:
                result.append((message, 'positive'))
            if message.find(':(') != -1:
                result.append((message, 'negative'))
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ab = APIBundle('my-secret-name')
    print(self.get_emotions())
```

Comment: This is the approach I've now used. Works like a charm. Thanks @jbndlr !

Comment: Happy to help. You may accept the answer then for others who find this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with `self.data=None` , or make an instance variable and call whenever you need. writing algorithm will make this thing more complex try to solve issue with inbuilt functions or with algorithm program vulnerability will affect alot.